# Numeric value is not a number?

Tags: php, input, fopen

I've just started learning PHP, i'm trying to get a numeric input by using fopen. The program should just ask user to type a number, and echo if the number is odd, even, or not a number. The thing is, no matter what I type, it is never considered as a number. Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

echo "Entrez un nombre: ";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$nbr = fgets($handle);
if (is_numeric($nbr))
{
    if ($nbr % 2 == 0)
        echo "Le chiffre $nbr est Pair\n";
    else if ($nbr % 2 == 1)
        echo "Le chiffre $nbr est Impair\n";
}
else
    echo "'$nbr' n'est pas un chiffre\n";
?>
```

At this point, I can type anything I want as an input, but the answer is always
"'[what I typed]
' n'est pas un chiffre"

Comment: `trim($nbr)` before you check if it's a number.

Comment: just var_dump($nbr) gives us output

Answer (score 3):

`fgets` gets a line from the stream, including the trailing newline character. `$nbr` is thus `"123\n"`, which is not numeric.

You can check this by printing `strlen($nbr)` (is `2`) and then `ord($nbr[1])` which prints `10` - the ASCII code for the newline character.

Use `trim($nbr)` to remove the newline character, and also additional whitespace before and after the input.